# Jquery fade from inside iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe

The below script fades in and out div #1. If div #1 is inside an iframe called testframe, how do you call the div from the parent?

```
<script>
document.onmousemove = (function() {
 var onmousestop = function() {
  $("#1").fadeOut(1000);
 }, thread;

return function() {
 clearTimeout(thread);
  thread = setTimeout(onmousestop, 2000);
   $("#1").fadeIn(500);
 };
})();
</script>
```

Thanks,
Scott

Edit: I should point out, same domain.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("iframe").contents().find("#1").fadeIn();
```